# SwiftUI AVCaptureSession Freezes other Views in a VStack or ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, avfoundation

I have a view which contains some few texts, button and camera view inside a scroll view

```
         VStack {
            ZStack{
                ScrollView{
                    
                    HStack(alignment: .top) {
                        LogoMainView()
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 44, alignment: .leading)
                    .padding(.horizontal,5)
                    VStack{
                        HeaderText(title:"Some header")
                        ParagraphText(text:"Some random text")
                        CameraDropDown(
                            toggleFront:{
                                self.captureSession.changeOrientation(orientation: .front)
                            },toggleBack: {
                                self.captureSession.changeOrientation(orientation: .back)
                            })
                      CameraView()
                        .onAppear(){
                        self.appDelegate.captureSession.setup()
                        self.appDelegate.captureSession.start()
                        }
                       .onDisappear(){
                          self.appDelegate.captureSession.stop()
                        }
                       .onChange(of: self.appDelegate.captureSession.orientation){
                         newvalue in
                         self.appDelegate.captureSession.orientation = newvalue
                         self.appDelegate.captureSession.setup()
                         self.appDelegate.captureSession.start()
                        }
                        
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal,10)
                }
            }
        }
        .clipped()
       }
```

Whenever the camera starts on clicking CameraDropDown it should change the orientation but expanding then choosing the desired orientation but when the CameraView() is running i.e (the camera is showing) it just does not respond to touches but when i switch of the CameraView() it the responds to the touchess and orientation changes.

What i have tried is to profile for hangs but i could not get a hang.

here is my cameraclass

```
//
//  CaptureSession.swift

import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import SwiftUI

class CaptureSession: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?
    @Published var orientation: AVCaptureDevice.Position = .back
    
    var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?
    
    func setup() {
        var allowedAccess = false
        let blocker = DispatchGroup()
        blocker.enter()
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { flag in
            allowedAccess = flag
            blocker.leave()
        }
        blocker.wait()
        if !allowedAccess { return }
        
        if !allowedAccess {
            print("Camera access is not allowed.")
            return
        }
        
        let session = AVCaptureSession()
        session.beginConfiguration()
        
        let videoDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: orientation)
        guard videoDevice != nil, let videoDeviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoDevice!), session.canAddInput(videoDeviceInput) else {
            print("Unable to detect camera.")
            return
        }
        session.addInput(videoDeviceInput)
        session.commitConfiguration()
        
        let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "SampleBuffer"))
        if (session.canAddOutput(videoOutput)) {
            session.addOutput(videoOutput)
        }
            self.captureSession = session
    }
    
    func start() {
        guard let captureSession = self.captureSession else {
            return
        }
        
        if (!captureSession.isRunning) {
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
                captureSession.startRunning()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func stop() {
        guard let captureSession = self.captureSession else {
            return
        }
        if (captureSession.isRunning) {
            captureSession.stopRunning()
        }
    }
    
    func changeOrientation(
        orientation:AVCaptureDevice.Position) {
            guard let captureSession = self.captureSession else {
                return
            }
            if(captureSession.isRunning){
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.orientation = orientation
                    self.setup()
                    self.start()
                }
                
            }else{
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.orientation = orientation
                    self.setup()
                    self.start()
                }
            }
            
        }
}

extension CaptureSession: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.sampleBuffer = sampleBuffer
        }
    }
}
```

how can I make the camera run and also respond to the touches for the other views that I have or what am I doing wrong here? Please help.

Comment: You are blocking the main thread with all those blockers convert what you need to async await or use completion handlers

Comment: which blockers as i am kind of new to swiftui